# Dissertation results section - report variables or operationalizations?

Tags: academic-writing

Following APA style - Do I report my results in the dissertation using the **variables** I'm researching or their **operationalizations**?

For example, which is style is correct:

1. The correlation between verbal ability and mathematical ability was significant.
2. The correlation between the reading comprehension test and the MAQ test was significant.

Comment: Why does this have thee close-votes for being "a question about existing literary works"?! OP is quite clearly asking for help with a dissertation he is *currently writing* - which is still off-topic, but for a completely different reason.

Comment: AGREE with @F1Krazy, this is a completely valid question on writing, it discusses a question which has a clear answer for experts. Like me! Nor is this a matter of "opinion". There are protocols and guidelines to follow. Not every question about writing has to be answerable by laymen, many questions are only answerable by people with relevant experience and education. This is one of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either way could work, but given this specific choice with no further information, I (a former university professor, a PhD, currently a full time research scientist) would report the version with the **tests**, what you call operationalizations.

The correlation could presumably be dependent upon something specific about your method of measurement (the test questions, in your example), or the protocol, meaning the experimental setup, the way you screened your subjects, WHERE you chose your subjects, what the questions on the test were, etc.

For example, if you failed to screen for native speakers, a native French speaker in an American sixth grade classroom, speaking English for less than year, will likely perform rather poorly on a reading comprehension test.

Those things can matter. Claiming that scores on **your** particular reading comprehension test are indicative of "reading ability" is a generalization you should avoid.

There are caveats: If you have shown elsewhere in the dissertation (in the section describing your measures) that your test, candidate screening and so on is something copied from another researcher and is the scientific community standard for assessing "reading ability". Then using the generalized term "reading ability" may be appropriate.

Another caveat is if you are using somebody else's published data, and their terminology. If Smith called it "reading ability" in his paper, I would mention that future references to "reading ability" refer to results of applying Smith's measure and protocol.

The final caveat, to make the "variables" version work, is to do all this when you describe your test and the protocol you used to administer it. Then you can title that subsection "Reading Ability Assessment", describe the test and protocol, and say "henceforth we refer to these results as 'Reading Ability'."

The point is to be clear and transparent; and for a dissertation you don't care about the length or page count. (Unlike a journal article where you might have a page limit.)